# How to sort regardless of case with Comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am using the `Comparator` interface to sort objects in ascending order using following code fragment:

```
final List<LinkModelSpi> documentLinks = this.documentLinksModelSpi.getDocumentLinks();

//Add This method for Sorting Document Link View Same Order. Now The application display same links order
// in catalogue administration edit drug window
if (Checks.checkNotNullAndNonEmpty(documentLinks)) {
  if (this.documentLinksModelSpi.getDocumentLinks().iterator().next() instanceof DocumentLinkModelSpi) {
    Collections.sort(documentLinks, (Comparator<? super LinkModelSpi>) new Comparator<DocumentLinkModelImpl>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(DocumentLinkModelImpl o1, DocumentLinkModelImpl o2) {
        return o1.getResource().compareTo(o2.getResource());
      }
    });
  } else {
    Collections.sort(documentLinks, (Comparator<? super LinkModelSpi>) new Comparator<LinkModelImpl>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(LinkModelImpl o1, LinkModelImpl o2) {
        return o1.getResource().compareTo(o2.getResource());
      }
    });
  }
}

//Collections.reverse(documentLinks);
for (final LinkModelSpi documentLinkModelSpi : documentLinks) {
  //noinspection unchecked
  ((DtoPresentationModelSpi<?, MDTO>) documentLinkModelSpi).addPropertyChangeListener(this);
}
```

The final result is this:

[image: Given Result]

But I want to sort list like this:

[image: expected result]

Where the links are sorted regardless of case. How can I do this?

Comment: Does `getResource` return a string?

Comment: @AndrewLi yes ,it return ABC, www.google..com..., Z. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's comparing strings lexicographically, so capital letters come before lowercase letters. What you can do is ignore case by using the builtin `String#compareToIgnoreCase`:

```
return o1.getResource().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getResource());
```

Or you could by making both operands in the comparison lowercase with `String#toLowerCase`:

```
return o1.getResource().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.getResource().toLowerCase());
```

That way, there will be no capitals to skew the results and only the letter will be taken into account when sorting.

---

Note: Sorting strings lexicographically means that `"www.google10.com"` *will come before* `"www.google9.com"` because strings are compared character-to-character and `"1"` is lexicographically less than `"9"`.

Comment: Thank You.. I think error is resolved.but I will check  further and Come with comment.

Comment: can I use to o1.getResource().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getResource()); this ? i used this but sorting not happening correctly.

Comment: Note that `toLowerCase` might be problematic for international strings (Turkish letters i/I are funny in that sense).

Answer (score 2):

The generic solution is to use [`java.text.Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html), which is a specialised `Comparator` that not only handles uppercase/lowercase, but can also deal with diacritic signs (such as ä and ë) and knows about locale differences (e.g. most Western languages put the ë with the e, but Finland puts it after the z).

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collator en_US = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
        Collator fi_FI = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("fi", "FI"));

        // Optional configuration; read the Javadoc for more information
//        en_US.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
//        en_US.setDecomposition(Collator.FULL_DECOMPOSITION);

        List l = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Azz", "ämm", "aaa"));
        Collections.sort(l, en_US);
        System.out.printf("en_US: %s\n", l);
        Collections.sort(l, fi_FI);
        System.out.printf("fi_FI: %s\n", l);
    }
}

// Output:
// en_US: [aaa, ämm, Azz]
// fi_FI: [aaa, Azz, ämm]
```